# Strange interaction between PyTorch and ONNX

Tags: pytorch, onnx, onnxruntime

I'm getting some strange behaviour from PyTorch, and in particular in how it interacts with ONNX. In summary:

- If I run an ONNX model then a PyTorch model, both are deterministic.
- If I run a PyTorch model then an ONNX model, neither is deterministic.

I have constructed a simple minimal working example, which:

- Defines and saves a model in both ONNX and PyTorch format.
- Loads the models and runs them in the order requested.

The example requires a new python session between each run. To attempt to reproduce, do the following:

- Run the thing with `initialise=True`
- Restart kernel/session. Set `initialise=False`. Run the thing.
- Restart kernel/session. Set `torch_first=True`. Run the thing.

Here are my relevant versions:

```
functorch==2.0.0
numpy==1.24.4
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu11==11.7.101
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12==12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11==11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12==12.1.105
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11==11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12==12.1.105
nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.5.0.96
nvidia-cudnn-cu12==8.9.2.26
onnx==1.15.0
onnxruntime-gpu==1.15.1
pytorch-lightning==2.0.9.post0
torch==2.1.0
torchmetrics==1.2.0
```

My cuda info:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.85.12    Driver Version: 525.85.12    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   32C    P0    32W /  70W |    175MiB / 15360MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     37885      C   ...da/envs/sun/bin/python3.8      172MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The code:

```
import sys
import onnxruntime
import numpy as np
import glob
import random
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

from collections import Counter
from tqdm.auto import tqdm


######################
# At the very least...
######################

seed = 8675309

random.seed(seed)
np.random.seed(seed)

torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)

torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False
torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)

#########################
# Define the torch model.
#########################

class MWE(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, img_ch=3, n_conv_layers=4):
        super(MWE, self).__init__()
        
        self.convs = nn.Sequential(*[
            nn.Conv2d(img_ch * 2**i, img_ch * 2**(i+1), kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1, bias=True)
            for i in range(n_conv_layers)
        ])
        
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.convs(x)
        flat = self.flatten(x)
        return torch.mean(flat)

    
################################
# Options for running the thing.
################################
    
# The first time we run, we want to set up the model, initialise the
# weights, and save to disk.
initialise = True
#initialise = False

# Do you want to run ONNX model first or Torch model?
torch_first = False
#torch_first = True

# The main thing we're looking at is running predictions on pre-trained models,
# but optionally you can run the predictions in the same session
run_predictions = not initialise
#run_predictions = True


################################
# Set up Torch and ONNX models.
################################

# Define the model.
img_ch = 3
n_conv_layers = 5
input_size = (1, img_ch, 16, 16)
model_torch = MWE(img_ch, n_conv_layers).cuda()

# Either save or load!
model_torch_weights_file = 'model.pt'
model_onnx_filepath = 'model.onnx.pt'

if initialise:
    # Save the torch model.
    model_torch.eval()
    torch.save(model_torch.state_dict(), model_torch_weights_file)
    print(f'Torch model saved to {model_torch_weights_file} :)')
    
    # Save an ONNX version.
    torch.onnx.export(
        model_torch,
        torch.rand(size=input_size, device='cuda', dtype=torch.float32),
        model_onnx_filepath,
        verbose=False, 
        input_names=[
            "input",
        ],
        output_names=[
            "output",
        ],
        opset_version=14,
        export_params=True,
        dynamic_axes={
            "input": {
                0: "batch_size",
            },
            "output": {
                0: "batch_size",
            },
        },
    )
    print(f'ONNX model saved to {model_onnx_filepath} :)')
    
else:
    # Load up the torch model.
    weights = torch.load(model_torch_weights_file)
    model_torch.load_state_dict(weights)
    model_torch.eval()
    print(f'Torch model loaded from {model_torch_weights_file} :)')

    # Always load the ONNX model from disk.
    model_onnx = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(
            model_onnx_filepath,
            providers=['CUDAExecutionProvider'],
        )
    print(f'ONNX model loaded from {model_onnx_filepath} :)')
    

#####################################################
# Now run some stuff! And watch the world fall apart!
#####################################################

if run_predictions:
    # Define randomly a tensor / numpy array with same values.
    tt = torch.rand(1, 3, 16, 16, dtype=torch.float32, device='cuda')
    nt = np.array(tt.detach().cpu(), dtype=np.float32)

    def predict_torch(tt, n=1000, precision=8):
        torch_results = []
        with torch.no_grad():
            for _ in tqdm(range(n)):
                pred = model_torch.forward(tt)
                pred_rounded = round(float(pred), precision)
                #print(pred)
                torch_results.append(pred_rounded)
        return torch_results

    def predict_onnx(nt, n=1000, precision=8):
        onnx_results = []
        for _ in tqdm(range(n)):
            pred = model_onnx.run(["output"], {"input": nt})[0]
            pred_rounded = round(float(pred), precision)
            #print(pred)
            onnx_results.append(pred_rounded)
        return onnx_results

    # Now run it in whichever order we've chosen.
    if torch_first:
        print('\nTorch results:')
        print(Counter(predict_torch(tt, 1000, 8)))
        print('\nONNX results:')
        print(Counter(predict_onnx(nt, 1000, 8)))
    else:
        print('\nONNX results:')
        print(Counter(predict_onnx(nt, 1000, 8)))
        print('\nTorch results:')
        print(Counter(predict_torch(tt, 1000, 8)))
```

In the event that this problem can't be reproduced, I may well be able to do a clean reinstall of my Python environment and forget about it.

But still, it's a weird thing to happen and I would very much like to know what is going on, and why this could happen!

Here are some screenshots of the results when running the predictions in each order:

[image: results from running ONNX model first]

[image: results from running Torch model first]

Thanks in advance for helping me solve this mystery!